# strcpy c++ cannot convert parameter 1 from string char*

Tags: c++, strcpy

i am trying to put the words that there are in a txt file* into an array of strings.
But there is an error with the strcpy(). it sais: 'strcpy' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *' . Why is that? Isn't it possible to create an array of strings like this in c++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void ArrayFillingStopWords(string *p);

int main()
{
   string p[319];//lekseis sto stopwords
   ArrayFillingStopWords(p);
   for(int i=0; i<319; i++)
   {
       cout << p[i];
   }
   return 0;
}

void ArrayFillingStopWords(string *p)
{
    char c;
    int i=0;
    string word="";
    ifstream stopwords;
    stopwords.open("stopWords.txt");
    if( stopwords.is_open() )
    {
       while( stopwords.good() )
       {
           c = (char)stopwords.get();
           if(isalpha(c))
           {
               word = word + c;
           }
           else
           {
               strcpy (p[i], word);//<---
               word = "";
               i++;
           }
       }
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "error opening file";
   }
   stopwords.close();
}
```

Comment: you really should consider refactoring your method of reading words. What if the file does not exist? Do you really want to display 319 empty strings? Are you sure that you'll always get 319 words? Why not 318 (or even worse) 320? Make it `C++` by using `std::vector<std::string>`, don't use character-wise read from file, use a simple `>>` instead and split at non-alpha characters if necessary (a sample of your text file would help to suggest the best approach here)

Comment: The file exists for sure..it's a part of a homework :), the words are 319 for sure too. Also the words at the txt file are one at each lane.

Comment: Imagine that there might be a following exercise which involves a bigger file. Do you really want to rewrite your code? No, you want the code to be able to cope with all sorts of files. The key is _beeing lazy_ and not to hard code such numbers.

Comment: you're totally right about this you propose to use an array list for this?

Comment: I _recommend_ `std::vector` for this purpose, but any _dynamic_ storage is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest `strcpy (p[i], word);` be changed to `p[i] = word;`.  This is the C++ way of doing things and takes advantage of the `std::string` assignment operator.

Comment: This works..i thought i didn't have oneother option except strcpy. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `strcpy` here. A simple assignment will do it: `p[i] = word;`. `strcpy` is for C-style strings, which are null-terminated arrays of characters:

```
const char text[] = "abcd";
char target[5];
strcpy(target, text);
```

Using `std::string` means you don't have to worry about getting the size of the array right, or about calling functions like `strcpy`.